How can I fit an HVAC vent louver alongside door casing?
We are redoing our bathroom and this is the last piece of the bathroom remodel puzzle (besides caulking and paint touch ups).
The old register is nasty looking and broken and needs to be replaced. It’s not worth trying to repaint or anything like that. It looks like the old owner just cut off the left part of the register. This leaves me a nice 6x12 hole.
The issue with just picking any old wall vent cover is the molding. The left is completely tight to the molding and no vents would fit without cutting out the molding or modifying the vent. We would much prefer to not cut out the molding if at all possible.
What would you all do?
P.S. I know the ‘baseboard’ is door trim. My wife really wanted it and our floor is flat enough to not need to scribe anything out. We both think it looks fine.


I'm not sure what problem you're facing. Plenty of louvers are surface-mount, so the size and shape of the duct opening are largely irrelevant. FYI, "flush with" doesn't mean the same as "tight to".

Can you find+buy a 6" by 10" (anything less than 12") register to to the job, and plaster in a vertical 2" strip on the left?

I see three options to avoid cutting the molding:

Cut the vent (register).
Use a register that's less wide, e.g. instead of a register for a 12x6 duct use one for a 10x6 duct.
Shift the duct opening a couple inches to the right to accommodate the
flange of the register.


#3 should be #1, in my book. It's the simplest approach and may not have any real downsides.

I wish I could do #3, but that is a huge undertaking. It would involve 5/8” plaster repair and cutting out/moving a load bearing stud. When they framed up the house, they framed it with a 12” gap between the studs in that area specifically for the air vent. Also, all the vents in my house are solid, non-flexible venting.

@isherwood depending on the tools available, they are listed in order of amount of work.

@JamoKisor what do you mean by "solid, non-flexible?"  Standard galvanized sheet metal?  If so, it's still possible to shift at least the opening a couple inches sideways.

@JamoKisor, I think you misunderstand #3. It's just a matter of screwing the thing to the wall with no other modifications.

@isherwood actually, the OP understood what I meant.  Are you suggesting simply expanding the hole in the drywall and not actually shifting the duct?

No. I'm suggesting simply laying a vent over the existing opening, as I stated. That's all it needs.

@isherwood so #2.  The actual box of OP's register (vent) was presumably sized to fit the actual duct opening.  You'd need a register with a smaller box to fit it without having to shift the duct opening and/or hole.

Not all registers have boxes which extend into the wall. OP should find one without a box. That's the point I've been trying to make all over this page. :)

I see.  That is true.  I was assuming the OP wanted an adjustable register.

When it comes to moving the actual ductwork/opening, that’s a no go. There are studs on both sides of the galvanized sheet metal that makes up the ducting. The span between the studs are exactly as wide as the ducting, so 12” apart vs the normal 16” on center that the rest of the wall has. I have decided to screw in a piece of 2x4 onto the side touching the door molding and to get a smaller 6”x10” register and I should be able cover all of the gaps that are not going to be covered by the frame of the register with some 20min mud and caulk.

If the duct is relatively tight to the drywall, you could just buy an "airvent cover". This is an almost flat piece of metal or plastic, with holes for the air to pass through. You can screw it on the wall, even though the duct behind it is not as wide as the cover.
You may benefit from plastering in a narrow piece of drywall on the left side and painting the edge on right side black. This would make it look symmetric if the wall is visible through the cover.

This is my proposal as well, but you can get overlay louvers which also allow some control over airflow.
